# How do I detect live stream resolution in Red5?

Tags: streaming, resolution, red5

How do I detect live stream resolution in Red5?
I do override  streamPublishStart(IBroadcastStream stream) where (correct me if I'm wrong) stream starts:

```
public void streamPublishStart(IBroadcastStream stream) {
        IConnection connection = Red5.getConnectionLocal();
    log.info("W3C x-category:stream x-event:publish c-ip:{} x-sname:{} x-name:{}",
            new Object[] { connection != null ? connection.getRemoteAddress() : "0.0.0.0", stream.getName(), stream.getPublishedName() });

}
```

Where I can access **stream** object. 
How do I check it's resoluton? 
I did tried **stream.getMetaData().getHeader()** but it gives me *Header is null* error. 
I have googled problem and I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to decode the incoming data to get the information that you require. Red5 does not decode the streams out-of-the-box. The only information we pull is the AVC and AAC coded "config" data and I wouldn't call that "decoding" per-se. The config will only give you a minimal amount of information about AVC/h.264 or AAC media. You can see the configuration information in these two classes:

https://github.com/Red5/red5-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/red5/codec/AVCVideo.java

https://github.com/Red5/red5-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/red5/codec/AACAudio.java

The "stream" shown in the method signature you've posted will be a [ClientBroadcastStream](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server-common/blob/master/src/main/java/org/red5/server/stream/ClientBroadcastStream.java) in most if not all cases. You can review the incoming audio and video data by extending this class or creating your own listener.

Lastly, the getMetaData() method will only return something of value to you if the broadcaster or the file source has provided the meta data content; in addition, the "Header" will not contain the bitrate.

MetaData class: https://github.com/Red5/red5-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/red5/io/flv/meta/MetaData.java

Header class: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server-common/blob/master/src/main/java/org/red5/server/net/rtmp/message/Header.java

Answer (score 1):

Since this isn't directly possible I'll use ffmpeg to download 5s part and than check it's bitrate with ffprobe:

```
ffmpeg -t 5 -re -i "rtmp://192.168.1.102/ntcServer/glosno live=1 timeout=5" -y -c copy test.flv
ffprobe -pretty test.flv 2>&1 | egrep 'bitrate: '
```

Thanks Mondain.